# How to check if JsonNode has array - Java, SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have I JSON that I need to iterate trough and if that JSON has list with key ´sibling´ iterate trough add those values to new list and return it if JSON doesn't have list with key ´sibling´ don't do anything

```
private List<SiblingsGameDataResponse> extractSiblingList(JsonNode node) {
        JsonNode siblings = node.get("siblings");
        ArrayNode siblingsArrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
        List<SiblingsGameDataResponse> siblingList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (siblings.isArray()) {
            siblingsArrayNode = (ArrayNode)siblings;
            for (Iterator<JsonNode> i = siblingsArrayNode.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                siblingList.add(new SiblingsGameDataResponse(asString(i.next(), "gameId")));
            }
            return siblingList;
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

My code is braking on part

```
if (siblings.isArray()
```

When I don't have list with key ´"sibling"´ in JSON and it gives me `NullPOinterException`.

Comment: So why not checking nullity before? `if (siblings != null && siblings.isArray()){.....}`

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: @user9347049 please attach full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your json is

```
{
  "siblings": null
   ...
}
```

a **NullNode** object will be returned

In case other json keys exist but "siblings" key is absent

```
{  
    "name": "someName"
     ...
}
```

then `JsonNode siblings = node.get("siblings");` will return **null** as it does not find any node with that key.

So first check if this node exist before checking if it is an array

`if (siblings != null && !siblings.isNull() && siblings.isArray()){.....}`

`siblings.isNull()` will check if that returned object is a NullNode

Another way around would be to effectively use `hasNonNull(String fieldName)` method before reading siblings. This would make sure that a not null value could be read and also a not NullNode would be read.

```
if (node.hasNonNull("siblings")){
   JsonNode siblings = node.get("siblings");
     if (siblings.isArray()) {
       ....
      }
}
```

**Also based on your question it might be that you have a typo**

> When I don't have list with key ´"sibling"´ in JSON it gives me NullPOinterException

You need sibling**s** key not sibling

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And what if it doesn't have what should I return, since return should be type `List<SiblingsGameDataResponse>`?

Comment: @user9347049 there is not a definite answer to what you should return. It is how you make the conception of it working. IMO I would try to return an empty ArrayList